# How to change debug msg color in Ansible according to regex?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Is there a way to change Ansible's debug color according to keywords inside of the debug message?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question

> *Is there a way to change Ansible debug color according to keywords inside of the debug message?*

Not I am aware of or out-of-box.

It might be possible to change or enhance an existing [Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) to

> *add new behaviors to Ansible when responding to events.*

To get a first insight one could have a look under  [`/ansible/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback) into [`default.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py) and search for `colorize`, `C.COLOR_*`, etc.

**Further Reading**

- [Developing plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html)
- [Callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins)